# Prolog: Take the first "N" elements of a list

Tags: list, prolog

I need to write a Prolog predicate `take(L, N, L1)` which succeeds if list `L1` contains the first `N` elements of list `L`, in the same order. For example:

```
?- take([5,1,2,7], 3, L1).
L1 = [5,1,2]
?- take([5,1,2,7], 10, L1).
L1 = [5,1,2,7]
```

Prolog thus far is making little sense to me, and I'm having a hard time breaking it down. Here is what I have so far:

```
take([H|T], 0, []).
take([H|T], N, L1) :-
   take(T, X, L2),
   X is N-1.
```

Can you please explain what I did wrong here?

Comment: You should accept @false's answer. It is more accurate.

Comment: Just a sidenote, it's a best practice to put recursive calls at the end of a recursive rule. In this original example, where would X reach 0? I haven't tested this particular program but I would surmise that at some point the list would simply run out of elements and return false, which would then start stepping back and triggering X is N-1. The reverse case though, adding an element to a list, let's say a random integer? You set X to 10 because you want 10 elements. X is then never decremented and the program loops until it runs out of memory.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a definition that implements the relational counterpart to `take` in functional languages like Haskell<sup>1</sup>. First, the argument order should be different which facilitates partial application. There is a cut, but only after the error checking built-in `(=<)/2` which produces an `instantiation_error` should the argument contain a variable.

```
take(N, _, Xs) :- N =< 0, !, N =:= 0, Xs = [].
take(_, [], []).
take(N, [X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :- M is N-1, take(M, Xs, Ys).

?- take(2, Xs, Ys).
   Xs = [], Ys = []
;  Xs = [_A], Ys = [_A]
;  Xs = [_A,_B|_C], Ys = [_A,_B].
```

Note how above query reads:

> How can one take 2 elements from `Xs` to get `Ys`?

And there are 3 different answers. If `Xs` is empty, then so is `Ys`. If `Xs` is a list with one element, then so is `Ys`. If `Xs` has at least 2 elements, then those two are  `Ys`.

---

<sup>1) The only difference being that `take(-1, Xs,Ys)` fails (for all `Xs, Ys`). Probably the best would be to issue a `domain_error` similar to `arg(-1,s(1),2)`</sup>

Comment: Could you avoid the cut by having the three cases be non-overlapping: 1) N=0, so 'yield' an empty list, 2) N>0 and an empty list, so 'yield' an empty list, and 3) N>0 and a non-empty list, so recurse?

Comment: @ScottHunter: Yes, indeed, but this would then be a waste. I'd do it when using `#>` instead.

Comment: Do the answers of `?- take(2.5, Xs, Ys).` make sense to you? I find them somewhat puzzling...

Comment: @false. OK, makes sense to me now. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

findall/3 it's a bit the 'swiss knife' of Prolog. I would use this snippet:

```
take(Src,N,L) :- findall(E, (nth1(I,Src,E), I =< N), L).
```

Answer (score 3):

The [code by @CapelliC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27205600/4609915) works **if** the instantiation is right; if not, it can show erratic behavior:

```
?- take(Es, 0, Xs).
**LOOPS**                   % trouble: goal does not terminate

?- take([A,_], 1, [x]).          
true.                       % trouble: variable A remains unbound
```

To safeguard against this you can use
[`iwhen/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449516/4609915) like so:

```
take(Src, N, L) :-
   iwhen(ground(N+Src), findall(E, (nth1(I,Src,E), I =< N), L)).
```

Sample queries run with SWI-Prolog 8.0.0:

```
?- take([a,b,c,d,e,f], 3, Ls).
Ls = [a,b,c].

?- take([a,b,c,d,e,f], N, Ls).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

?- take(Es, 0, Xs).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

?- take([A,_], 1, [x]).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Safer now!

Comment: It seems a good style to follow the syntax of `when(Cond, Goal_)` for tests of instantiation that is `( ground(Es) -> take_unsafe(Es, N, Xs) ; throw(error(instantiation_error,_),_) )`.

Comment: @false. What about processors that do not offer `when/2`?

Comment: My comment was only about the **form**. That is, instead of extra clauses with cut, rather use the form above.  No more than that.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by "above"?

Comment: @false. Good one. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution would be:

```
take(List, N, Prefix) :-
    length(List, Len),
    (   Len =< N
    ->  Prefix = List
    ;   length(Prefix, N),
        append(Prefix, _, List)
    ).
```

Less thinking means less opportunity for mistakes. It also makes the predicate more general.

Comment: HET! This implies that `List` has `N` elements. But it should also succeed for `List = []`

Comment: @false Yes, now I saw the examples.

Comment: You current solution implies that the `List` is a list, thus of finite length, but only a prefix is needed, if at all.

Answer (score 1):

your base case is fine

```
take([H|T], 0, []).
```

And also you can say what if N is 1

```
take([H|T],1,[H]).
```

But you recursive case some variable is not defined like L2. So we can write this as

```
take([X|T1],N,[X|T2]):-
N>=0,
N1 is N-1,
take(T1,N1,T2).
```

which case all varibles are pattern-matched.

Comment: You could also use
`take([_|_], 0, []).`
`take([H|_],1,[H]).`
for the first two lines to have anonymous variables instead of getting singleton variable error.

Answer (score 0):

take(L, N, L1) :- length(L1, N), append(L1, _, L).

Comment: This infinite-loops at the end of e.g.: take([a, b], N, L).

Answer (score 0):

This is performant, general and deterministic:

```
first_elements_of_list(IntElems, LongLst, ShortLst) :-
    LongLst = [H|T],
    (   nonvar(IntElems) -> Once = true
    ;   is_list(ShortLst) -> Once = true
    ;   Once = false
    ),
    first_elements_of_list_(T, H, 1, IntElems, ShortLst),
    (Once = true -> ! ; true).

first_elements_of_list_([], H, I, I, [H]).

first_elements_of_list_([_|_], H, I, I, [H]).

first_elements_of_list_([H|LongLst], PrevH, Upto, IntElems, [PrevH|ShortLst]) :-
    Upto1 is Upto + 1,
    first_elements_of_list_(LongLst, H, Upto1, IntElems, ShortLst).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- first_elements_of_list(N, [a, b, c], S).
N = 1,
S = [a] ;
N = 2,
S = [a,b] ;
N = 3,
S = [a,b,c].

?- first_elements_of_list(2, [a, b, c], S).
S = [a,b].
```

Below is a variant which also supports:

```
?- first_elements_of_list_more(10, [5, 1, 2, 7], L1).
L1 = [5,1,2,7].
```

```
first_elements_of_list_more(IntElems, [H|LongLst], [H|ShortLst]) :-
    once_if_nonvar(IntElems, first_elements_of_list_more_(LongLst, 1, IntElems, ShortLst)).

first_elements_of_list_more_([], Inc, Elems, []) :-
    (var(Elems) -> Inc = Elems
    ; Elems >= Inc).

first_elements_of_list_more_([_|_], E, E, []).

first_elements_of_list_more_([H|LongLst], Upto, IntElems, [H|ShortLst]) :-
    succ(Upto, Upto1),
    first_elements_of_list_more_(LongLst, Upto1, IntElems, ShortLst).

once_if_nonvar(Var, Expr) :-
    nonvar(Var, Bool),
    call(Expr),
    (Bool == true -> ! ; true).

nonvar(Var, Bool) :-
    (nonvar(Var) -> Bool = true ; Bool = false).
```

Comment: OP's example fails: `first_elements_of_list(10,[5,1,2,7],L1)`

Comment: Added variant to support: first_elements_of_list_more(10, [5, 1, 2, 7], L1).